# How to create a duplicate directory under parent then rename a file parent name in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, rename

I'm trying to convert a kluged together linux script to windows command line.
so, below is my script, not elegent but somehow it works.

```
rar a -r0 boomer.rar
#combines all the files into a rar file
mkdir 'rar - '"${PWD##*/}"
#makes a new sub-dir named the same as parent with "rar - " prepended
cp boomer.rar 'rar - '"${PWD##*/}"
#copies boomer.rar to the new folder (see below*)
rm boomer.rar
#removes rar file *becuse I couldn't just get it to move in linux
cd 'rar - '"${PWD##*/}"
# move focus to new dir
for fname in *.rar
do
mv $fname 'boomer - '"$(pwgen 26 1).rar"
done
#renames files
```

EDIT:

*[Adding this part to explain what I am trying to accomplish.
The purpose of this script is to rar all the files in a folder.
EX c:\boomer\egret
this creates boomer.rar
A New folder is created called "rar - egret"
C:\boomer\egret\rar - egret
boomer.rar is copied to "rar - egret" and deleted
change dir to "rar - egret" 
renames boomer.rar to "boomer - ahs7Ahxei2imah4tubiqu1eY2i.rar" 
then the whole "rar- egret" folder will be moved to a storage location later.]*

I can't figure out how to do "${PWD##*/}".
I need help with this part  Just getting the name of the directory only, not the path as well.

I am not a coder in any way. This is all kluged together from researching steps on forums like this. I am clueless and don't understand the code I used. I'm sorry, but sometimes the monkey hits the right keys.

I've been asked by members of my circle to make this work on Windows.  I'm working to the lowest common denominator here, so batch files.  No WSL being installed, just vanilla Windows.

If it's too difficult I'm OK with that. If more info is need I will provide as much as is required, but I don't know until told.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are not supposed to write the code for you.

what follows is tips on how to write it, I hope you can follow along.

The first command (mkdir)can only be accomplished with a small program so I am including it here, the rest will be suggestions on how to write it yourself, I hope this makes sense.

OK, so as far as I can tell there is no variable assigned the name of the immediate parent folder, but it this can still be done. Your first line will have to be replaced with this:

`call :Makedir`

then add this routine to the bottom of your script:

`:MakeDir`

`set _dir=%~p0`

`SET _dir2=%_dir:\= %`

`call :FindParent %_dir2:~1,-1%`

`mkdir "rar - %Parent%"`

`goto :eof`

`:FindParent`

`if "%1"=="" goto :eof`

`set Parent=%1 & shift & goto :FindParent`

...that will make your directory for you. The rest you will have to write yourself, but here is how to approach it:

In your next line `cp` would be replaced with `copy` and maybe throw in a "/y", so try `copy /y` in place of 'cp'. From a command line try `copy /?` for details.

In the next line `rm` would be replaced with `del /y` and maybe throw in a "/f", so try `del /y /f` in place of `rm`. From a command line try `del /?` for details.

You still need to move the file to the destination the equivalent of 'mv' is simply `move` ( `move /?` for details) and to generate a random character use %rnd%.  There is no `pwgen` equivalent in CMD.

I hope that is enough for you to figure it all out. It can be done, but I am not allowed to write it all out for you.

Comment: Ok, made a batch file with just the mkdir "rar - %cd%"   The result was d:\hold\Test>mkdir "rar - d:\hold\Test"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.         The not relevant comment was just in case someone was wondering why I was doing what I was doing. (sorry I can't seem to make hard returns in this comment box so everything is running together. )

Comment: Also, this the result I'm looking for is "rar - Test"

Comment: added more info to original post.

Comment: Larryc, thank you.  I really wasn't trying get it written for me.  I just had no idea where to start and what my options for code were.  Not even knowing the correct terminology makes it hard to goole. sorry I didn't make it more clear - I was only interested in knowing how to make the new dir, the rest was just provided for context to show what it was doing in the script. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: @danneauxs I didn't think you were asking me to write it for you, -and I'd be happy to do it for you anyway. But there will be people reading this who will not be happy if I did write it for you - sorry about that. Sometimes people just need a hand, that doesn't mean they are lazy. Good luck with that, I hope it works out well for you.

Comment: I realized your intent thank you.  I tried to avoid that by showing I had working code in linux.  The code I showed is from a working script that I use daily.  This isn't for me it for community of people that use windows not linux.  I do with one button click what takes them 3 gui programs to do.  All the CLI commands are available windows there's just no one to puzzle it all out.  You've helped remove that barrier.  This one little piece was the key to making it all work.  Thanks again my friend.